# The output is static in JavaScript cookie reading, help in debugging

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, cookies

Before I start, I am brand new to JavaScript and was given kinda a tough assignment for our level without being taught much.
So this is my problem: I modified the code from W3C.org for cookie creation, reading, and checking to include the 'visits' section (for hit counter) and made it so that the visits number will be increased by 1 every time the page loads (from server, not in offline mode).
But in the following program, the output is always "Visits: 1":

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays, visits) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
 var visit = (visits + 1);
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; visits=" + visit;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
 var visitCount = getVisits();
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Cookie: " + user + "\n" + "Visits: " + visitCount);
  setCookie("username", user, 365, visitCount);
    } else {
        user = "TheName"; alert("Cookie: " + user + "\n" + "Visits: " + visitCount); setCookie("username", user, 365, visitCount);
    }
}
//this is the place where the problem occurs, but not sure.
function getVisits() {
 var visit = getCookie("visits");
 var visitNumber = visit.substring(7);
 if (visitNumber == 1) {
  return visitNumber;
 }
 else {
 visitNumber += 1; return visitNumber;
 }
}
```

And in this program, the output is always "Visits: null" like the number was not outputted:

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays, visits) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
 var visit = (visits + 1);
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; visits=" + visit;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
 var visitCount = getVisits();
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Cookie: " + user + "\n" + "Visits: " + visitCount);
  setCookie("username", user, 365, visitCount);
    } else {
        user = "TheName"; alert("Cookie: " + user + "\n" + "Visits: " + visitCount); setCookie("username", user, 365, visitCount);
    }
}

function getVisits() {
 var visit = getCookie("visits");
 var visitNumber = visit.substring(7);\
// this is the change in the program from the first code
  if (visitNumber >= 1) {
  visitNumber += 1; return visitNumber;
 }
 else {
 return visitNumber;
 }
  }
```

What I am excepting overall is that I would be able to output the name and hit count by this program.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: You never update the cookie.

Comment: what do you exactly mean? Thank you for the response!